# How do you unit test a binding with a different name in an Angular 1.5 component?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components, angularjs-1.5

I have the following component:

```
angular.module('foo')
    .component('searchInput', {
        bindings: {
            text: "<query"
        },
        templateUrl: 'components/searchInput/searchInput.html',
        controller: 'SearchInputCtrl'
    });
```

For the following to pass:

```
expect(component.text).toBe('bar');
```

I have to use the following code:

```
    var component = $componentController('searchInput',
        {$scope: {}},
        {
            text: 'bar'
        }
    );
```

However, I want to test that the value being bound to 'text' is being sourced from 'query'.  This **does not** work:

```
    var component = $componentController('searchInput',
        {$scope: {}},
        {
            query: 'bar'
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can test this sort of thing by compiling the component. e.g.

```
inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
    var parentScope = $rootScope.$new();
    parentScope.myVar = 'test';

    var element = angular.element('<search-input query="myVar"></search-input>');

    var compiledElement = $compile(element)(parentScope);
    parentScope.$digest();

    var scope = compiledElement.isolateScope();

    expect(scope.$ctrl.text).toBe('test');
});
```

Comment: that crossed my mind but I want something more in line with what the Angular developer guide suggests: $componentController -- it's easy and you avoid DOM and thus the extra steps of compiling and digesting.

Comment: The more I've pondered this and looked at the Angular source, as @rob pointed out, working with DOM is the only way.  Since components are syntactic sugar for directives, I should have the same mindset/expectations when testing either of them.  When testing an (explicit) directive's controller via $controller I am fine specifying the name of the target binding; the same should be true with testing a component's controller via $componentController.  When testing the source attribute for a directive I use DOM and check isolateScope(); the same should be true with component source attributes.

Comment: I was having similar problem, when I passed a variable defined in binding like: `<my-component binding-var="string value"></my-component>` it didn't  work, but when I assigned the same thing in a scope variable and passed like: `<my-component binding-var="scope.myVariable"></my-component>` it worked not sure why?

Comment: @Pawan if `binding-var` uses a two way binding then you'd have to pass a literal string in like `<my-component binding-var="'string value'"></my-component>`

Comment: @rob I tried again but passing the string value directly doesn't set the binding variable in the component. It gets set only when I pass it through a variable on the scope.